# One form populating many tables

Tags: ms-access

I have 3 tables in Microsoft Access, e.g. A, B, and C. All three tables are linked by the name of a project (all projects are completely differently titled, so this isn't an issue, although I did link them all through ID number to see if that would work for my issue). Each table focuses on different aspects of the project (such as basic info, deeper explanation etc), so I'd like to keep them separate if possible.

What I want to do is create a form where I can enter the name of a project once (i.e. in one box) and it appears in all three tables, rather than having three boxes in one form that I would have to fill out with the same project name each time (or manually fill out a form per table each time there is a new entry).

Is there a way to do this in Access? I hoped linking them would work but no dice. I've searched for it but there really have been no answers I've found that are similar. Any help with this/the right key terms to search/the right forum would be appreciated.

Comment: There should be one KEY that is common to these three tables, and it sounds like it is ID number.  Good db design there for sez that something like project name should appear only in one place. So please redesign the tables if you are really using ID number.

Comment: Use form/subform arrangement. Link on ID. Do not save project name into all 3 tables. One table must act as master/parent in which the ID will be primary key and the other 2 tables will be dependent with foreign key.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think your scenario is a valid use-case for 1:1 relations (there aren't many valid cases). If all the data belongs to a project, then it should all be in one table.

If you really must use multiple tables, link them by ID, not by name. But you'll still have to provide code to sync the tables (e.g. generate a new record with the same ID in all tables at once).

But really, this is lots of work and room for errors for no real gain.

If you want to focus on separate aspects of a project, use queries or forms that show just that data.